# How would you recommend backing up my movie library on a Mid 2010 Mac Pro

Tags: macos, mac, backup, plex, mac-pro

I was gifted a Mid 2010 Mac Pro and am in the process of migrating my Plex library over to it.  It has 4 HD bays - 1 which runs the OS, 3 that are available.

I want to purchase 2 new HD's - one of which will provide me enough storage to fit the entire library and another to duplicate it the library over to as a backup.

My question is - what is the best way to do this?  Should I use Time Machine and run a nightly or weekly backup?  Should I make an attempt to set up a RAID?  Is there 3rd party software that I should look into?

The overall goal is to have data redundancy for the library in case the drive fails. I'm also looking for a solution that utilizes just this machine as buying a NAS is not in the cards for right now.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you haven't already, I'd get an SSD as a boot drive.<sup>[1]</sup>
Then 2 large capacity [3.5"] HDs for your storage & backup.<sup>[2]</sup>

As you won't expect the source HD to be particularly frequently updated - large movies, not a running OS with a million tiny files - then I'd use [Carbon Copy Cloner](https://bombich.com) to make infrequent backups. You could do this manually or use CCC to run on a schedule.

If you partition the backup drive [& it is large enough for backups of both], then make a smaller partition on the backup drive [HFS+] & use that as Time Machine backup for the boot drive.

This will put the least stress on the system.

Belt & braces if your backup HD is big enough, make a separate clone  of the boot drive with CCC too, on a third partition; then hide it from normal use with fstab - see [MAC: Make a Hard drive mount on request only](https://superuser.com/questions/999392/mac-make-a-hard-drive-mount-on-request-only)

***Nota bene:***
<sup>[1]</sup> You can put an SSD loose in the optical bay, doesn't need an adaptor bracket if you do that, you can just lay it loose. There are two SATA power/data plugs in there & very few Macs have two optical drives. Sack one if you need to, they're almost useless these days. The practical difference between running a modern SSD at 3gb/s compared to 6gb/s is negligible compared to the overall speed boost the SSD will give.
<sup>[2]</sup>HDs larger than 4TB have very annoyingly moved the mount holes. If you get drives with those 'won't fit' holes you will have to get new [drive sleds from OWC](https://www.owcshop.eu/catalog/product_info.php/hard-drive-sled-bracket-2009-2012-p-797) [I don't know of anyone else that's ever made them] Be sure to get the right ones. They're different for the 3,1 & earlier compared to the 4,1 & later, and are *not* interchangeable.

Comment: Hey thank you very much this is extremely helpful.  Fortunately the computer was already transitioned to an SSD for boot so that is already taken care of.  I will buy CCC and use that to backup my collection from New Drive 1 to New Drive 2.  I may repurpose an old drive to for Bay #4 to backup the OS but I'm much less concerned about the OS drive failing and having to redo that than I am having to replicate all the movies.  Thank you so much!